# Tensorflow: The Session graph is empty. Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, session, tensorflow2.0

Hello guys I am using Tensorflow 2.0

and in these lines of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello World')
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
sess.run(hello) <-- Error in this line
```

> RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph
>   before calling run().

Any idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok guys I found the way:

```
g = tf.Graph() 
with g.as_default():   
  # Define operations and tensors in `g`.   
  hello = tf.constant('hello')   
  assert hello.graph is g

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=g) 
sess.run(hello)
```

> b'hello'

**thank you for your time!**

Comment: Tensorflow core r2.0 have enabled eager execution by default. so, without changing it
we just have to change our code as like as below

Comment: with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    # Building a graph
    hello = tf.constant("hello")
    print(sess.run(hello))

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow core r2.0 have **enabled eager execution by default**. so, without changing it we just have to change our code as like as below by **Launch the graph in a session.**

```
> with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
>     # Building a graph
>     hello = tf.constant("hello")
>     print(sess.run(hello))
```

According to the Tensorflow doc..

> A default Graph is always registered, and accessible by calling
>   tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph

For this basic operations not required to declare a **tf.Graph()** , you can define a graph which has more computations and dataset you can define a graph and invoke into the session.

Please Refer: For More informations
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph
https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/400