# 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session' - TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having issue with Session module.

```
import tensorflow as tf
n1 = tf.constant(3.0)
n2 = tf.constant(4.0)
print(n1)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run([n1,n2]))
```

below is the console output I have received.

```
runfile('C:/Users/Rushabh Shah/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Rushabh Shah/.spyder-py3')
tf.Tensor(3.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Rushabh Shah\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 11, in <module>
    sess = tf.Session()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142951/tensorflow-2-0-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-session. Not sure what your version is, but maybe this can help.

Comment: Yes this is useful. But after this I am getting new error as below

Comment: tf.Tensor(3.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rushabh Shah\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(sess.run('Hello'))  File "G:\Rushabh_Shah\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)  File "G:\Rushabh_Shah\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1105, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366789/tensorflow-the-session-graph-is-empty-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `sess = tf.Session()` to `sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()` , it will work.

source : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *Tensorflow 2.0* you should use `sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()` instead of `sess = tf.Session()`.